# Calculating the order of permutation subgroup generated by 3 elements

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I’m calculating the automorphism group of $\mathrm{GP}(8,3)$ (generalized Petersen graph [GP(8,3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyawQ.png), but it doesn’t matter for this question). Let $A := \operatorname{Aut}(\mathrm{GP}(8,3))$.

I know $A \leq S_{16}$, $|A| = 96$, and that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in A$.

$\alpha = (1, 7, 8)(2, 15, 13)(3, 12, 5)(6, 11, 9)$

$\beta = (7, 1)(6, 2)(5, 3)(15, 9)(14, 10)(13, 11)$

$\gamma = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)(8, 9, 10 ,11, 12 ,13, 14, 15)$

I can see why $|\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rangle| \geq 24$, since $\alpha^3 = \beta^2 = \gamma^8 = 1$.

Is there any way to show that $|\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rangle| = 96$, which would mean $\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rangle = A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that the group $G=\langle\alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle$ acts transitively on 16 points. Now note that
$$\delta=\alpha\beta=(2,9)(3,12)(6,13)(7,8)(10,14)(11,15)
$$
and
$$
\epsilon=\alpha\gamma^2=(2,9,16)(3,14,8)(4,6,13)(7,10,12)
$$
(I multiply permutations left to right, otherwise you need to reverse the product order) are both in the stabilizer of $1$, and have orders $2$, respectively $3$. Thus the stabilizer has at least order $6$, and the whole group at least order $6\cdot 16=96$.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's so simple now that you explained it.